# Enabling Intel VT-d in the BIOS causes sound to fail

Tags: audio, vt-d

I have a Gigabyte GA-X79-UD3 motherboard and when I activate VT-d in the BIOS, I no longer get sound.

What can I do to avoid this problem?

Comment: Disable VT-d? :)

Comment: I have the same problem.. obviously this is bad because some people want to have both virtual machine and sound on the host.

Comment: @BoppityBop I have no XPs with VirtualBox (as you mentioned bellow) and IOMMU, but if everything is set properly, it's probably a board bug, but I don't see any fix on this http://www.gigabyte.com/products/product-page.aspx?pid=4050&dl=1#bios

Comment: This is probably a common problem http://forums.whirlpool.net.au/archive/1922493

Answer (score 1):

Intel VT-d is "Virtualization Technology for Directed I/O" (IOMMU), used for re-mapping devices to virtualized guests. From your question is not clear your situation but I guess you have nothing to do with virtualization, so keep VT-d disabled.

In case you do virtualization and re-mapping soundcard to the guest, it's correct that soundcard has been unbinded from the host.

Comment: I have virtual box and it doesn't use sound. and I still have audio disable on the host.... it seems to me that this is the mobo/dirvers thingy rather than VT-d itself in this case (I have GA-X79-UD3)

Comment: @BoppityBop same mobo, same issue

Comment: @Gleno and BoppityBop, AFAIK VirtualBox doesn't support VT-d (IOMMU). This feature is still experimental, for more details follow [this document](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch09.html#pcipassthrough). Make sure you have unbinded soundcard from the host also I can recommend to prevent loading this soundcard on host by kernel boot parameters (or disable alsa at all). Also consider full virtualization of the soundcard, it will be available for both systems.